# Parity of solutions to the Abel equation of the second kind $yp-y=f(x)$ for even and odd $f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, even-and-odd-functions

Consider the Abel equation of the second kind,
\begin{align}
yp-y=f(x);\quad [p=y'_x]
\end{align}
for some arbitray non-zero function $f$.

Suppose $y$ were an odd function, then $p$ is even and it follows that
\begin{align}
yp-y=-f(-x)=f(x).
\end{align}
So odd $y \implies$ odd $f$. Is the opposite true? Does odd $f \implies$odd $y$ ?

---

My attempt: Suppose $f$ is odd, then
\begin{align}
y(x)p(x)-y(x)+y(-x)p(-x)-y(-x)=0
\end{align}
Any function can be decomposed into the sum of an odd function and an even function, i.e. $y(x)=o(x)+e(x)$. This gives that
\begin{align}
(o+e)(o'+e')-(o+e)+(-o+e)(o'-e')-(-o+e)=0,
\end{align}
since $o(-x)=-o(x)$, $e(-x)=e(x)$, $o'(-x)=o'(x)$, and $e'(-x)=-e'(x)$. Upon simplifying I find that
\begin{align}
(o(x)e(x))'=e(x).
\end{align}
So  $o(x)\equiv0 \implies$ $e(x)\equiv0$. Therefore, $y$ cannot be even if $f$ is odd. But $y$ can still be a combination of even and odd. I am also interested in the cases where $y$ is even and where $f$ is even.